Problem with statistical charts in per-diem management applications
I have a problem with statistical charts in per-diem management applications:
Firstly, my chart includes 3 axes, y-axis 1 is the column that displays the cost of the finished schedule (blue cols), y-axis 2 is the red line about the sum of separated schedules of employees (even if they are going altogether in a schedule by created admin as considered as ones). Eventually, chart results showed that they will be grouped by each month in a year.
Secondly, I completely finished but my tutor in thesis graduation said I need to add more about the schedule not finished(still in progress) info in the chart
I'm still dull and not sure, because if the schedule not finished then costs haven't been calculated yet which will make my statistics being wrong about that month.
Is that possible in business problems or per-diem applications?
